# How use push to create a new array? Unexpected error

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, push

I have this code below

```
let geese = ["African", "Roman Tufted", "Toulouse", "Pilgrim", "Steinbacher"];
let array = ["Mallard", "Hook Bill", "African", "Crested", "Pilgrim",  "Toulouse", "Blue Swedish"];

function gooseFilter(array, geese) {
     var name = [];
     for (let i = 0; i < geese.length; i++) {
         if (array.includes(geese[i])) {
             name.push(geese[i]);
         }
         return name;    
     }
}

gooseFilter(array);
```

and I have an error 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined', and I don't know why. Do you have any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: `gooseFilter(array,geese  );` instead of `gooseFilter(array);`

Comment: You'll also need to put the return out of the for loop. Your code code be simplified to `const result = geese.filter(e => array.includes(e))`

Answer (score 3):

You forget to pass the second args. And your return statement should be out of loop. consider the following snippet:

```js
let geese = ["African", "Roman Tufted", "Toulouse", "Pilgrim",
    "Steinbacher"
];
let array = ["Mallard", "Hook Bill", "African", "Crested", "Pilgrim",
    "Toulouse", "Blue Swedish"
];

function gooseFilter(array, geese) {
    var names = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < geese.length; i++) {
        if (array.includes(geese[i])) {
            names.push(geese[i])
        }
    }
    return names;
}

console.log(gooseFilter(array, geese));
```

Answer (score 2):

You declare a variable named `geese` here:

> ```
> function gooseFilter(array, geese) {
> ```

Then you define it here:

> ```
> gooseFilter(array);
> ```

Since you pass only one argument, the second (`geese`) is `undefined`.

---

If you want to access the `geese` variable declared in the wider scope, then **don't mask it with another variable of the same name**.

```
function gooseFilter(array) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
function gooseFilter(array, geese) {
```

make it

```
function gooseFilter(geese) {
```

Answer (score 0):

call gooseFilter(array); with second argument

```
let geese = ["African", "Roman Tufted", "Toulouse", "Pilgrim", 
"Steinbacher"];
let array = ["Mallard", "Hook Bill", "African", "Crested", "Pilgrim", 
"Toulouse", "Blue Swedish"];

   function gooseFilter(array, geese) {
   var name = [];
   for (let i=0; i<geese.length; i++) {
     if (array.includes(geese[i])) {
     name.push(geese[i])
    }
   return name;    
  }
    }

  gooseFilter(array,geese);
```

Comment: You are looking for [intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You defined function `gooseFilter` which accepts two arguments, but then, when calling it you pass only one param to it:
`gooseFilter(array)`.

You have to pass both defined arrays to your function:
`gooseFilter(array, geese)`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mistakes in your code:

1. You defined function `gooseFilter` with 2 params but call with only one `array`, this cause `geese` is `undefined`. That why you got error

> 'length' of `undefined`

2. You `return` in the `for` loop. This will make the loop stop after the first item.

The code should be

```js
let geese = ["African", "Roman Tufted", "Toulouse", "Pilgrim", 
"Steinbacher"];
let array = ["Mallard", "Hook Bill", "African", "Crested", "Pilgrim", 
"Toulouse", "Blue Swedish"];

function gooseFilter(_array, _geese) { // parameter # variable
     var name = [];
     for (let i=0; i<_geese.length; i++) {
       if (_array.includes(_geese[i])) {
       name.push(_geese[i])
       }
       // return name;  <-- Return here will stop the loop after the first item
     }
     return name; // return here instead
     
}

const rs = gooseFilter(array, geese) 

console.log(rs)
```